# Joining fragments of messages together

Tags: c++, stl

I need to write a function that can receive fragments of different messages, and then piece them together. The fragments are in the form of a class `msg`, which holds information of

```
int message_id
int no_of_fragments
int fragment_id
string msg_fragment
```

The function needs to do the following

1. Check received message - if `no_of_fragments == 1` then the message has not been fragmented and function can stop here
2. If `no_of_fragments > 1` then message is fragmented

   - get `message_id` and `fragment_id`
   - collect all fragments e.g. for `message_id`=111 with `no_of_fragments`=6, the system should ensure that `fragments_id` 1-6 have been collected
   - piece fragments together

What is the best way for doing this? I thought a map might be useful (with the `message_id` serving as key, pointing to a container that would hold the fragments) but would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: Yea that should be good enough, a `std::map<int, std::vector<FragmentData> > >` or if you have available use `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Is it safe to assume you'll be processing a set of messages with (nearly) contiguous `message_id`s at any given time? If so, I'd probably use an `std::deque`, kept in order by `message_id`, where you keep track of the smallest message_id in the deque at any given time. Then you can index directly to the spot for any other message. If the `message_id`s are sparse, you might want to store them in a heap instead -- still going to store the data much more densely than a map.

Comment: I think my answer is best, though.  Don't worry about whether they come in in order, use minimal memory, and have constant time insertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a map of vectors.  Each time you receive a new message ID, use that as your map key.  Then allocate a vector to hold the fragments based on the number of fragments specified in the first fragment received (doesn't have to be in order).  You'll also need to hold the count, so it's easy to know when you've received the last fragment, so probably a map of message_id to a struct of count and the vector of fragments.

My c++ is rusty:

```
struct message_parts {
  int fragments_expected; // init to no_of_fragments
  int fragments_received; // init to 0 (you'll bump it as soon as you add the fragment to the vector)
  vector<fragment *> fragments; <-- initialize size to no_of_fragments 
}

std::map<int, message_parts> partial_messages
```

When you insert a fragment, put it directly into the location in the fragments vector based on the fragment_id - 1 (since they are zero-indexed).  This way you'll always have them in the right order, no matter the order they come in.

After you add a fragment, check to see if fragments_received == fragments expected, and then you can piece it together and deal with the data.

This gives constant time first-fragment detection and allocation, constant time fragment insertion, constant time complete-message-received detection, and linear time message reconstruction (can't do any better than this).

This solution requires no special casing for non-fragmented data.

Don't forget to delete the fragments once you've reassembled them into the complete message.